# defined hive variables not available with fat-free-framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm defining a couple of hive variables but after a page reload they are no longer available. This method is called by my controller render method. So I want to retrieve some sql data and store it in an array within the hive and allow the user to walk through it record by record. it will later be called by some javascript code. The problem is I store the variable but on reload it is not defined. Am I missing the point of the hive? or just doing something wrong. This is all being done under the same session

```
function apiGetSupplies() {
    $supplies = array();
    if ( $this->f3->exists( 'supplies' ) ) {
        $supplies = $this->f3->get('supplies');
        $counter = $this->f3->get('counter');

        echo json_encode($supplies[$counter]);
        $counter++;
        $this->f3->set('counter',$counter);
    } else {
        //some sql call to define supplies 
        $this->f3->set('supplies',$supplies);
        $this->f3->set('counter',0);
    }
}
```

Comment: the hive is just a key-value store for the current request. if you want something to persist for the current user session, store it within the SESSION, like `$f3->set('SESSION.foo', 'bar')` ;-)

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks